# Is there a term for insincere prefacing?

Tags: neologisms, rhetorical-devices, parentheticals

Is there a specific term for the practice of prefacing a statement with another statement that is in contrast (in spirit) to what is being said?

There is a related concept called apophasis, where you deny calling something to attention, but nevertheless bringing up the subject. But the intent is different, since the purpose here is to offer a pre-emptive denial before bringing up something negative or controversial.

**Examples**:

I am not a racist, but this neighborhood would be better with less [x] people.

We shouldn't gossip, but did you hear what Joseph said to Mary?

**Related concept**: Is there a related term for prefacing a criticism with an unrelated positive statement so as to reduce the negative impact of the criticism?

**Example**:

A corporate email from an office manager that begins with "I hope everyone is having a great Monday." before lambasting the employees for not cleaning up after the Friday office party.

Comment: I hear *protesting too much* even in a short opening of *Not a racist but* or *Not to gossip but*.

Comment: [Rational Wiki claims](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/I%27m_not_prejudiced,_but...) "I am not a racist, but..." is called a **false front** or **but-head**, but I don't find much evidence for these terms.

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIT15cJ3y50

Comment: I'd say *apophasis* works. *But* is a trigger word for this. See https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-apophasis-rhetoric-1689115

Answer (score 1):

I have called them *mitigating disclaimers* before for lack of a better term, but I think they might also broadly fall under the modern *polite formula*,  like the classic *with all due respect*.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely a matter of opinion how much we should classify initial *I hope everyone is having a great Monday* as somehow "incompatible" with following text lambasting the employees for not cleaning up after the Friday office party.

But in terms of "grammatical terminology", if two text "incompatible" text elements appear in the same utterance, that utterance would be an...

> [**oxymoron**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oxymoron) (Merriam-Webster)
> *a combination of **contradictory or incongruous** words*